# Updating react typings; Unable to find 'react' in the registry

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings

I noticed my react typings dont seem to be the right version, ie @types/react (15.0.35) but using react (15.6.1) in my project so I'm trying to update the typings. I tried:

typings install react@15.6.1

but got the err: Unable to find 'react' ('npm') in the registry

[image: error]

I'd like to update the typings to the version of react that I'm using (15.6.1) not to the latest typings, and I don't really want to update my project to the latest version of react.

Answer (score 0):

Please stop using `typings` it's deprecated https://github.com/typings/typings as you can see in the github project.

Please use @types scope...

```
npm install --save @types/react@15.6
```

If you have problems using this approach please show your tsconfig.json